# SQL Server 2008R2 "Force" Stored Proc Creation Despite Dependency Errors

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Wondering if this is possible.

I'm working on ironing out some source control differences between our database environments using RedGate SQL Source Control.

A couple of procedures that I am trying to script rely on some Linked Servers. While I have been able to script the Linked Servers with default passwords (so they do exist, at least technically), they have some unknown provider (it's listed as an OLEDB Provider, with no indicator of what specifically it is).

Bottom line is these all fail because of these Linked Server references in the stored procs ("Data source name not found and no default driver specified").

While I track this down, I would like to at least create the stored procedures like views are, even though the dependency can't be resolved, so that SQL Source Control no longer displays these as New changes that need to be pulled down.

I don't want to ignore them because they do need to be fixed (which is why I am choosing not to add them to the RedGate tool's Filters).

Is it possible to force creation of the stored procedure in spite of the missing dependency?

Comment: Put the four-part calls in dynamic SQL - then they aren't validated at parse/compile time. However, what is the rush to create a procedure that will fail when you execute it? Can't you just tell RedGate to ignore those procedures temporarily? Why deploy something you know is broken?

Comment: Im averse to doing that too. It will cause a diff, which I want to avoid. The primary issue is there are users who are doing pulls via RGSC and all objects that haven't been created yet (because the Linked Servers are broken) are still showing up as NEW items, so others try to pull them down. It has been difficult finding out who created this Linked Server. I just prefer not to hide it using a Filter, where it can potentially be forgotten about. And to add, they are not technically broken (they function fine in production).

Comment: Well, sorry, there's no magic that will solve all of your requirements. There is no deferred name resolution for linked servers unless you defer parsing altogether (which requires dynamic SQL) or you create a fake linked server that contains the referenced objects.

Comment: I'm going to assume you're not using "magic" pejoratively; it was, as I see it, not a question completely out of left field given how views behave. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Deferred name resolution works for object name references, the same way in views and stored procedures. Deferred name resolution does not work for column names, linked server references, etc.